# Infinite loop in before_update callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update translations, but it becomes to infinite loop, because in **perform** method I repeat saving. How I can solve this problem?

`before_update :update_translations, on: :edit`

```
  def update_translations
      id = self.id
      order = Order.find(id)
      locale = order.translations.find(order.translation.id).locale.to_s
      TranslateOrderFeedbackWorker.perform_async(id, locale)
  end
```

```
def perform(id, current_locale)
    order = Order.find(id)
    I18n.locale = current_locale
    text = order.feedback
    translator = TranslateTextService.new

    I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
      next if locale.to_s == current_locale

      I18n.locale = locale
      order.feedback = translator.translate(text, current_locale, locale.to_s)
    end
    order.save # <= infinity loop here
  end
```

Comment: you can use **attr_accessor** to prevent this

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to get around this would be to add a virtual attribute on the model, which tells it whether to run the job or not:

```
# in your model
attr_accessor :translated

# in your update_translations method
unless translated
  TranslateOrderFeedbackWorker.perform_async(id, locale)
end

# in your job
order.translated = true
order.save
```

You could alternatively make `translated` an actual column in the database - the code would be the same but you wouldn't need the virtual attribute (the `attr_accessor`).

If there are a lot of these sort of flags (the record must go through a pipeline of transformations), you might consider using a state machine such as [aasm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm).